# Como exportar graficos a excel

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy realizando un grafico comparativo y tengo problemas al exportarlo a excel, estoy atascado ojala puedan ayudarme este es el código el cual al ejecutarlo funciona.
He mirado en la web y solo encontré una manera pero es utilizando canvasJS.chart y no se como pasar esta información a esa libreria espero puedan ayudarme con esta inquietud y poner fin a este dolor de cabeza jajaja, de antemano muchas gracias. sin nada mas que agregar me despido esperando que puedan ayudarme a salir de este embrollo.

```
    <?php
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/css_nuevo.css');
?>

<script src="/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery/css/jquery-ui.css">

<script>
    $(function() {

        $.post("/mintutorpopup/cminimoesperado",function( data ) {
            $( "#divPopup1" ).html( data );
        });

        $( "#btnPopup1" ).click(function() {
            $( "#divPopup1" ).dialog({
                height: 420,
                width: 880,
                show: { effect: "blind", duration: 500 },
                title: "Avance Mínimo Recomendado"
            });
        });


    });
</script>
<div>

    <style>

        #apDiv1 {
            position:absolute;
            background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #99CC00;
            border-top:1px solid #99cc00;
            height:1px;
            margin-top:<?=231-($this->layout()->EL_AVANCE_MINIMO*15)?>px;
            z-index:1;
            background-color: #99CC00;
        }

        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale {
            height: 230px;
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-top: 31px;
            width: 360px;
        }

        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale ul {
            float: left;
            height: 200px;
            list-style: outside none none;
            margin: 0 0 0 6px;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            width: 30px;
        }

        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale ul li.perc_passato {
            background-color: #ffa41a;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        #fondo_graf {
            height: 330px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 414px;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #mar li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=3;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;

                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }

        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #apr li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=4;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #mag li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=5;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #giu li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=6;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #lug li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=7;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #ago li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=8;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #set li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=9;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #ott li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=10;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #nov li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=11;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }
        #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #dic li.perc_passato{
            height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=12;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
        }

    </style>

    <style>

        @media print {


            #apDiv1 {
                position:absolute;
                background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #99CC00;
                border-top:1px solid #99cc00;
                height:1px;
                margin-top:<?=231-($this->layout()->EL_AVANCE_MINIMO*15)?>px;
                z-index:1;
                background-color: #99CC00;
            }

            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale {
                height: 230px;
                padding-left: 30px;
                padding-top: 31px;
                width: 360px;
            }

            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale ul {
                float: left;
                height: 200px;
                list-style: outside none none;
                margin: 0 0 0 6px;
                padding: 0;
                position: relative;
                width: 30px;
            }

            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale ul li.perc_passato {

                background: #ffa41a none repeat scroll 0 0;
                border-color:  #ffa41a;
                solid-color:  #ffa41a;
                border-left: 2px solid #ffa41a;
                border-right: 2px solid #ffa41a;
                border-top: 2px solid #ffa41a;
            }

            #fondo_graf {
                height: 330px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 414px;
                z-index: 0;
            }

            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale ul li {
                bottom: -1px;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 10px;
                left: -1px;
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                width: 30px;
            }



            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #mar li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=3;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;

                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }

            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #apr li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=4;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #mag li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=5;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #giu li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=6;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #lug li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=7;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #ago li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=8;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #set li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=9;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #ott li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=10;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #nov li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=11;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
            #css_grafico_colonne_verticale #dic li.perc_passato{
                height:<?php $LLAVE_MES=12;

                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) {
                            $VAR_PROMEDIO=$this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES];

                            if ($VAR_PROMEDIO > 13) {
                               $ALTO_COLUMNA=13*15;
                            } else {
                                    $VALOR1=$VAR_PROMEDIO*15;
                                    $VALOR2=(round((number_format($VAR_PROMEDIO,1)-$VAR_PROMEDIO)*15));
                                    $ALTO_COLUMNA=$VALOR1+$VALOR2;
                            }
                            echo $ALTO_COLUMNA;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo ("0");
                        }   ?>px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</div>
<
<div style="float:left; width: 410px;">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" class="tabla excelExp" >
              <tr>
                <td width="50%" colspan="6" bgcolor="#E9E9E9" class="titulo_tabla excelExp"><strong>Indicador de avance</strong></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="21%" height="47" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2"><strong>Avance acumulado</strong></td>
                <td width="11%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?=round($this->layout()->AVANCE_ACUMULADO,1)?></td>
                <td width="21%" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2"><strong>Mes actual</strong></td>
                <td width="11%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?=round($this->layout()->PROMEDIO_ACTIVIDADES_MES,1)?></td>
                <td width="25%" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2"><strong>M&iacute;nimo recomendado</strong></td>
                <td width="11%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?=$this->layout()->EL_AVANCE_MINIMO?></td>
              </tr>
</table>
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" class="tabla" >
              <tr>
                <td height="230" colspan="6"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <div id="fondo_graf"><img src="/img/css_grafico_colonne_verticale_bg.jpg" width="400" height="260" /></div>
                    <div id="apDiv1"></div>                    
                        <div id="css_grafico_colonne_verticale">
                        <ul id="mar">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=3;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="apr">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=4;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="mag">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=5;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="giu">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=6;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="lug">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=7;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="ago">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=8;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="set">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=9;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="ott">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=10;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="nov">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=11;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="dic">
                            <li class="perc_passato">
                            <?php   
                        $LLAVE_MES=12;
                        if (isset($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES])) 
                            echo (number_format($this->layout()->AL_AVANCE_PROMEDIO_MENSUAL[$LLAVE_MES],1));

                        else 
                            echo("0");

                        ?></li>
                        </ul>
</div>                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%" height="30" style="font-size: 10px"><div style="font-size: 10px; border-top:2px solid #99CC00;float:left;margin-left:40px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:7px;width:10px;"></div>M&iacute;nimo recomendado</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="font-size: 10px"><div style="font-size: 10px; background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFA41A;float:left;height:10px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:2px;width:10px;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;"></div>Avance mensual</td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="85" colspan="6" valign="top">Este es el indicador de Avance Mensual del curso.
                    Corresponde al promedio de actividades realizadas por los alumnos.
                    La línea verde representa el avance mínimo mensual recomendado para el nivel escolar.<br />
                  <div class="btn_unic" style="margin-top:7px;"><a href="javascript: " class="lightwindow" id="btnPopup1">*Ver tabla de avance m&iacute;nimo  recomendado</a></div>
                  </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
    </div>

<div id="divPopup1" style="display: none"></div>
```

Comment: Siempre puedes editar tu pregunta con el enlace ['editar'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/269564/edit) que aparece debajo. Ahí puedes añadir todo el código, los logs de error que creas relevantes, etc. Debajo sólo van las respuestas que te ofrezcan otros usuarios.

Comment: OK gracias por la aclaración